# Can we construct a Chern-Simons theory provided that the ground state is degenerate and gapped, like the Abelian fractional quantum Hall effect?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

I am studying the Chern-Simons approach to fractional quantum Hall effect, which a special focus on the topological order in the context of Abelian fractional quantum Hall effect.
To me, the logic to adopt (Maxwell-) Chern-Simons theory as an effective theory is pretty bottom up (says, Wen's book): We can write down a current with fractional Hall conductivity, from which we can introduce the statistical gauge fields as auxiliary fields for the effective action and it turns out to be the Chern-Simons theory. However, it seems to me that the concept of topological order is mainly based on ground state degeneracy and gapped bulk systems.

My questions are:

1. Consider systems satisfy (my prototype example is Laughlin's state at filling 1/m): (i) gapped bulk; (ii) degenerate ground state; (iii) $U(1)$ charge conservation; (iv) only one kind of fractional excitation. What are the extra minimal ingredients needed to derive the corresponding effective (topological) action? Is it possible to derive the Chern-Simons theory directly, only based on these constraints?
2. Also, can the fractional Hall conductivity be derived solely from these constraints?

Comment: Is there a precise definition of what you call "gapped and degeneracy constraints"?

Comment: I may try to expand this into an answer later, but: (1) No, different Chern-Simons theories can have the same ground state degeneracy, (2) No, the derivation of the Hall conductance relies on U(1) charge conservation, but the gap and ground state degeneracy of quantum Hall phases don't require U(1) symmetry.

Comment: @d_b. Thanks for your reply! Regarding the Hall conductance, what if the charge is also assumed, in addition to ground state degeneracy and gapped bulks?

Comment: @Seth Whitsitt. Thanks for your reply! By gapped, I mean that the energy difference between the ground state and the first excited states is non-zero. By degeneracy, I means that the ground state is degenerate. (What I have in mind is the Abelian fractional quantum Hall effect at filling 1/m, for example.)

Comment: @d_b. Regarding your first comment, "different Chern-Simons theories can have the same ground state degeneracy", can you explain more on this? For example, what distinguish different gapped states with the same ground state degeneracy? What if I further assume that there is only one kind of fractional excitation. For example, are the following four constraints enough to specify one underlying theory?  i) ground state degeneracy; ii) gapped bulk; iii) one kind of fractional excitations; iv) charge conservation. If yes, can I derive Chern-Simons theory directly from these constraints?

Comment: @Richard With only that information, I agree with d_b's comment: one needs more information than just the presence of a gap and the degeneracy of the ground state to know the CS theory describing the system.

Comment: @Seth Whitsitt. Thanks for the comment. What if I further assume that  i) one kind of fractional excitations; ii) charge conservation? I have update the question to include this

Comment: @Seth Whitsitt. I think a better rephrase of the question here is that what is the minimal ingredients that enable us to derive the Chern-Simons theory directly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is basically yes, if we are willing to accept an algebraic description of 2+1D gapped phases. In this algebraic description, one does not resort to a particular field theory. Rather, we abstract out "universal" properties of low-energy localized excitations, the anyons. The mathematical structure is called a modular tensor category (MTC). In this theory, all such excitations can be classified into a few "elementary" types (and their "direct sums"). Two excitations can be fused to form another excitation. MTC also contains information about braidings between anyons and mathematical consistency conditions for fusion and braiding.

The only tricky question is what you mean by "having only one kind of excitation". If that means there is just one type of nontrivial anyon in the MTC, then the internal mathematical consistency of MTC only allows two possibilities: either a semion theory, e.g. $\nu=1/2$ Laughlin state, or Fibonacci anyons (assuming the system is bosonic. For fermions there is one more choice). So this is probably too restricted.

A slightly different way to proceed is to assume that all anyons are Abelian. What it means is that the quantum state of the system is uniquely determined once the locations of the anyons are fixed. It can be shown that if the anyons are Abelian, then the universal properties can be captured by a $U(1)\times U(1)\times\cdots$ Chern-Simons theory. Now if we further assume that all anyons can be "generated" by a fundamental one from fusion, then it must be a simple U(1) Chern-Simons theory.

U(1) symmetry can also be incorporated into this framework abstractly, and one can indeed derive various constraints on what the Hall conductance could be based on very general considerations.